# Using GeoFire to save current location in Firebase (React Native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, geofire

I am trying to use GeoFire in my React Native application to get the currently authenticated user's location and save this as a GeoLocation in the Firebase database.    I can't find an actual example of working code to do this anywhere on the net.

This is what I am trying:

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
var geofireUser = geofire(firebaseRef);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError:  Attempted to assign to readonly property.
```

I had this up and running fine in my Android Studio app, and the equivalent code above would create the following data in Firebase under the UID of the user:

```
DatabaseName:
  -Users
     -cdshnnHd8493jdNndi0
         -g:  fhejhe987
         -l:
             0: 0.324239
             1: 12.4587493
```

I just need to get React Native to a point where I am creating that code in the database again and it will unlock the whole spectrum of GeoFire commands for me, but I just can't get it working and there are just no resources for any of this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Geofire documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#new-geofirefirebaseref) you create a new instance with:

```
// Create a GeoFire index
var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
```

In your snippet it looks like you're trying to redefine the `geofire` module itself, hence the message.

Comment: Awesome man, the app no longer crashes, so that's something, but nothing is being written to Firebase still.   The entry for this user is empty after running this code, so not sure what this is actually doing.   Is this getting the user's current location?  Do I just need to write it to the database somehow?

Comment: The code you shared does write anything. I highly recommend studying the GeoFire documentation I linked to find out how to write geo-data, and how to subsequently query it.

Comment: That guide is exactly what I needed.   Was not able to find this before, the other guides have no code examples and so they are useless.   This doesn't tell me how I can get my current location coordinates so I assume that means this is not a function of geofire.    Thank you sir. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you some difficulties with `GeoFire` I propose you to use `react-native-geolocation-service` package, which works as needed for both IOS and Android platforms